# MS Access update record

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to update the records in an Access database where the column "Group" matches the argument.

The method I'm using at the moment is the following:

```
public void RenameGroup(string oldName, string newName)
{
    OpenConnection();
    command.Connection = con;
    command.CommandText = "Update [Data] SET [Group] = ? WHERE [Group] = ?";
    command.Parameters.Add("@oldName", OleDbType.Char).Value = oldName;
    command.Parameters.Add("@newName", OleDbType.Char).Value = newName;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseConnection();
}
```

The issue in this case I'm assuming it's that I'm trying to update the same column I'm iterating over and I need to use a Select query first, just not sure what would be the right way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't providing the parameters in the query.

Try:

```
command.CommandText = "Update [Data] SET [Group] = @newName WHERE [Group] = @oldName";
```

Comment: The question marks actually works as well (at least in access 2007) but your post made me spot the mistake I was doing. The first argument should be newName and the second one the oldName, thanks.